# MySQL throwing error “Statement is incomplete expecting ;” when trying to create trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I wanna create a trigger like this:

```
create trigger trigofstu before insert on student
for each row
begin
    if new.sage <18 then
        set new.sage = 18 ;
    end if;
end;
```

but i got the error like this:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5  0.016 sec

[image]

byw  i used mysqlWorkbench
thanks!!!

Comment: Try using `DELIMITER $$` before the `create trigger` statement.

Answer (score 2):

I have couple remarks about your code:

1. in case new.sage is null it still will be null after trigger execution
2. It's not good practice so save age in DB, it's changed in a time. Prefer to save birth-date or birth-year because it constant.

Any way, if you interesting in trigger way you can use next:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigofstu BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET new.sage = GREATEST(18, COALESCE(new.sage, 0)) ;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```